# Rails - Building a nested model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

```
Project (id)
Permission (project_id, user_id)
```

When trying to save a project, I get the following error: ActiveRecord::RecordNotSaved (You cannot call create unless the parent is saved):

Controller:

```
@project = current_user.projects.new(:name => params[:project][:name])
@project.permissions.build(:user_id => current_user.id)

respond_to do |format|
  if @project.save
  ......
```

Suggestions? Thansk

Comment: Sorry that should be @project. that was just a typo entering the question...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try setting `:autosave => true` on your association

```
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :permissions, :autosave => true
  …
```

Answer (score 2):

`current_user.projects.new` doesn't set `user_id` for a project, try to use `current_user.projects.build` instead.

Comment: That would merely assign nil to the Project instance's `user_id` if `current_user.id` is `nil`.

Comment: Now I know that #new and #build are aliases. So my answer is not true.